# DRV8801 H-Bridge : need for freewheeling diodes?

Tags: diodes, h-bridge

I'm designing a PCB using a [DRV8801PWP](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8801.pdf).

However, I'm a bit unsure if I need to add freewheeling diodes myself or not.
In the typical applications, they don't show them, but I didn't found either an explicit mention that I don't need them.

Some information that might be relevant :

- supply voltage : 12.6V max
- motor current : about 1A max (stalling)
- motor's load has rather low inertia (some motors are used in rough torque control (ie nearly immobile), and the others for the wheels of the robot (low speed, high reduction ratio)

So do I need to add free-wheeling diodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IC has body diodes quoted in the data sheet: -

[image]

These are the bulk diodes in parallel with the output MOSFETs. Here they are again: -

[image]

> *However, I'm a bit unsure if I need to add freewheeling diodes myself
> or not.*

You might only need to add them if you plan on using multiple DRV8801s in parallel (read section 9.3 - parallel configuration).

> *So do I need to add free-wheeling diodes?*

Are you planning on using parallel connected DRV8801s?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I wasn't sure if those where the body diodes of the MOSFETS or freewheeling diodes. So if they are the freewheeling diodes, then I'm fine